# Only one glossary of each type get printed

Tags: glossaries

I finally got the glossaries package to '*work*'. Not sure if I have incorrect installation or if I'm doing something wrong in the code. I want two types of glossaries, symbols and abbreviations. I get a list generated but it only shows the first value of each typed used.

[image: Only one glossary of each type in the list]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]       {symbols}       {not}       {ntn}       {Symbols}
\newglossary[alg]       {abbreviations} {abb}       {abr}       {Abbreviations}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LA}% label 
{% 
    type=abbreviations,% glossary type 
    name={LA},% 
    description={Los Angeles},% 
    sort={S}% 
}

\newglossaryentry{NY}% label 
{% 
    type=abbreviations,% glossary type 
    name={NY},% 
    description={New York City},% 
    sort={S}% 
}

\newglossaryentry{theta}% label 
{% 
    type=symbols,% glossary type 
    name={$\theta$},% 
    description={The angle of attack},% 
    sort={S}% 
}   
\newglossaryentry{alpha}% label 
{% 
    type=symbols,% glossary type 
    name={$\alpha$},% 
    description={The angle of measurements},% 
    sort={S}% 
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=symbols, title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=abbreviations, title={List of Abbreviations}]


\section{Section One}

Here are my two abbreviations \gls{LA} and \gls{NY}.\\
Here are my two symbols \gls{alpha} and \gls{theta}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not using `xindy` will provide both entries, as well as `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given all your entries the same `sort` value (`S`). This means that `xindy` can't differentiate between them and combines them. You can see this more clearly if you insert page breaks:

```
Here are my two abbreviations \gls{LA} and
\clearpage
\gls{NY}.

Here are my two symbols \gls{alpha} and
\clearpage
\gls{theta}.
```

[image: image of glossaries]

The entry for `alpha` has the locations 2 (corresponding to `\gls{alpha}`) and 3 (corresponding to `\gls{theta}`). Similarly the entry for `LA` has the locations 1 (corresponding to `\gls{LA}`) and 2 (corresponding to `NY`).

This is just the way that `xindy` treats entries with identical sort values, whereas `makeindex` will keep them separate although it's unable to sort them.

Is there any particular reason why you've used the same `sort` for all the entries? If you want an unsorted list, you're better off just using `\makenoidxglossaries` (instead of `\makeglossaries`) and `\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,...]` (or `sort=use`). If you want the entries sorted alphabetically, then just remove the `sort` key from the abbreviations (since the `name` provides a natural sort) and provide unique `sort` values for the symbols. For example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]       {symbols}       {not}       {ntn}       {Symbols}
\newglossary[alg]       {abbreviations} {abb}       {abr}       {Abbreviations}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LA}% label 
{% 
    type=abbreviations,% glossary type 
    name={LA},% 
    description={Los Angeles}% 
}

\newglossaryentry{NY}% label 
{% 
    type=abbreviations,% glossary type 
    name={NY},% 
    description={New York City}% 
}

\newglossaryentry{theta}% label 
{% 
    type=symbols,% glossary type 
    name={$\theta$},% 
    description={The angle of attack},% 
    sort={theta}% 
}   
\newglossaryentry{alpha}% label 
{% 
    type=symbols,% glossary type 
    name={$\alpha$},% 
    description={The angle of measurements},% 
    sort={alpha}% 
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=symbols, title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=abbreviations, title={List of Abbreviations}]


\section{Section One}

Here are my two abbreviations \gls{LA} and \gls{NY}.

Here are my two symbols \gls{alpha} and \gls{theta}.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Incidentally, the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package provides the command `\glsxtrnewsymbol` when the `symbols` package option is used, which sets the `sort` field to the label instead of the `name` value. So the above can be changed to:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[nomain,symbols,abbreviations,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle{short}

\newabbreviation{LA}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newabbreviation{NY}{NY}{New York City}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={The angle of attack}]{theta}{$\theta$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={The angle of measurement}]{alpha}{$\alpha$}

\begin{document}

\printsymbols[title={List of Symbols}]
\printabbreviations[title={List of Abbreviations}]


\section{Section One}

Here are my two abbreviations \gls{LA} and \gls{NY}.

Here are my two symbols \gls{alpha} and \gls{theta}.

\end{document}
```

which produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicola. The reason I was using 's' as sort is because I saw it used somewhere where I copied the entry-code. Thought it would stand for some Sorting-Method. I will go for the {glossaries-extra}.